# Check if passwordless access has been setup

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-keys

I would test via a python script whether a passwordless ssh login has been setup or not.
If i run the normal ssh command then it will wait to accept the password for some amount of time.
Is there a way where the ssh command should return an error as soon as ssh asks for a password.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ssh command accepts quite a large set of options, so assuming that your Python code is calling shell commands do the following :

```
ssh -oNumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 <host> "echo hello"
```

This will instantly fail if the keys have not been setup, and instantly complete if they have, which is the reason for the command being passed to the host. This gives you a simple test.

Comment: I guess `-oBatchMode=yes` also works. I wonder if BatchMode also skips other human interventions.

Answer (score 1):

paramiko will raise an `AuthenticationException` if you don't pass a password to the `SSHClient`'s `.connect()` method and a working key cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a parameter to ssh command to only try the public key in the  authentication process and set a batch mode with a command that always return true when the command is executed in the remote host. With that approach you can capture the exit code in the var $? and do some decision.

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o BatchMode=yes <host> /bin/true &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    #DO SOMETHING, THE CONNECTION WAS SUCCESSFUL
else
    #CONECTION DENIED
fi
```

You can capture custom output to a variable by finding the "Permission denied" in the verbose output of the ssh command as is in the following code.

```
PERMISION=$([ ! -z "$(ssh -v -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o BatchMode=yes <host> /bin/true 2>&1 | grep " Permission denied")" ] && echo "GRANTED" || echo "DENIED")
if [ $PERMISION == "GRANTED" ]; then
    #DO SOMETHING, THE CONNECTION WAS SUCCESSFUL
else
    #CONECTION DENIED
fi
```

I hope this find you useful .

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `PasswordAuthentication` option

> `PasswordAuthentication`
>   Specifies whether password authentication is allowed. The default is ''yes''. https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config

#### Python code

```
import subprocess
completed_process = subprocess.run(
    """ ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@localhost 'hostname' """,
    shell=True
)
assert completed_process.returncode == 0
```